# Can we use two class Diagrams for two apps -- child app and parent app

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I have two modules of an app. one is parent app and another is child app. should I create two different class diagrams for both apps or should there only be one diagram?

Comment: Draw as many diagrams as you need and not more. What do you mean by "modules of an App"?

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely up to you to decide.  Some thoughts that may guide you:

- If the classes or components of these both classes deal with parts of the same domain (for example, one app is maintaining a catalogue, and the other allows to purchase catalogue items), you may consider one **model**.
- If anyway you consider your apps two be just two faces of the same system,  you should consider one **model**.
- If the apps are two different things and only share some "modules", components, or classes (in a library),  you may consider two or three models.  THe package of the common part might then be imported into the model of the apps.
- One model does not mean one **diagram**:  in fact several diagrams may show the same model under different viewpoints.  So you might very well use several diagrams, each focusing on some elements of one of the app.
- You could even have one diagram to show the main classes of both apps and several other diagrams showing some of those classes as well as more detailed classes. The key is to keep each diagram of one model sufficiently simple to be easily understood.
- Whatever the situation, avoid a huge mega-diagram showing everything with 50 classes:  nobody except you would be able to absorb such a complexity.

If you're confused regarding the difference between **modeling** models and **drawing** diagrams, you may have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729609/3723423)

Comment: The power of wall paper diagrams is mainly to impress others ;-) But it can also help in navigating the model and find otherwise hidden relations. Of course, it's hard to produce/maintain so in most cases one would not put effort in such a monster.